# asynchronous beginwrite endwrite Unity (net 2.0)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, unity-game-engine, filestream

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to write some bytes (in this case a recorded .wav file) to harddisk in an asynchronous way.

I'm using unity so as far as I know I'm limited to using Filestream.BeginWrite and EndWrite.

What I got so far seems to be working, but I'm worried that, because of my lack of experience with asynchronous calls I'm not properly closing the filestream after it's done, leaking memory.

I'm starting the BeginWrite like so:

```
object t = null;

fileStream.BeginWrite(bytesData, 0, bytesData.Length, new  AsyncCallback(EndWriteCallback),  t);
```

Then I've got an EndWriteCallback that has this:

```
public static void EndWriteCallback(IAsyncResult e){
    FileStream fs = e.AsyncState as FileStream;
    fs.EndWrite(e);
}
```

Is this enough? Again, it seems to be working alright, but I feel like I'll have to call FileStream.Close() somewhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can `fs.dipose()` the filestream or you could use a [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: You need to pass `fs` in to `BeginWrite` instead of `t` to make `e.AsyncState as FileStream` work.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChristophKn mentioned in the comment above, `fs.dispose()` is probably the best way to release the resources.